# Using docker-compose in a GitLab CI pipeline for a Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to implement GitLab CI pipeline for my spring boot project

I use docker-compose to set up my database for the tests

My project use maven and jdk 11 that why I'm using maven:3.8.3-openjdk-11 image. I can't add another image so I tried to add socker as a service but is not working

this is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```yaml
stages:
  - build

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version"

before_script:
  - export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y docker.io
  - curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

maven_build:
  stage: build
  image: maven:3.8.3-openjdk-11
  script:
    - cd timetreelib
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean install

test:
  stage: build
  image: maven:3.8.3-openjdk-11
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: docker
  script:
    - cd timetreelib/docker/dev
    - docker --version
    - docker-compose up -d
    - docker logs docker
    - cd ../../
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
```

I tried some alternatives but this is kinda what I got

```
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ cd timetreelib/docker/dev
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.5+dfsg1, build 55c4c88
$ docker-compose up -d
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at [MASKED]. Is the docker daemon running?
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the value of your `DOCKER_HOST` variable? Do you also have the `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR` variable set?